# dynamo db fetching data from inner array

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Here is my data in dynamo db :

```
a: {
     "datetime": 'a',
     "description": "Ford Car",
     "offers": 
            [
             {
              "countries": [
               {
                 "code": "ALL",
                 "name": "Global"
               }
            ],
           [
             {
          "code": "As",
          "name": "Private"
        }
      ]


    }
  ]

}
```

I want to fetch all the offers that contains "code": "ALL"

I tried several things and gone through several solutions in stackoverflow .

Code i tried :

```
FilterExpression = "contains(offers.countries, :code)";
     ExpressionAttributeValues = {  ":code": {
      "countries": 
        {
          "code": "ALL",
          "name": "Global"
        }
    }
```

This is returning an empty array.